# Activator.CreateInstance timeout

Tags: activex

I'm trying to debug an unmanaged EXE through an ActiveX interface. The problem is that I'm using Activator.CreateInstance(Type) to create the ActiveX object of my application. The behavior I'm debugging is in the loading of this application.

As a result, my debug session prematurely terminates when the timeout for this method expires (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE). Is there a way to manually extend the timeout for this function? The ActiveX object is being created in a C# application.

Answer (score 1):

`CoCreateInstance()` timeout after 120 secondes. That's it. I'm not aware of a way to extend it.

Is there any way to execute the code you are trying to debug at a later stage rather than directly at component creation? That way you will be able to debug the code separately and since the component would already have been created, it won't timeout on the `CreateInstance()`.

Comment: I found out that the code I needed to debug was actually independent from the start up process. I'm going to leave this question open in case someone does have a solution.